# How to export jcr-node for module bootstrapping

Tags: jcr, magnolia

Let's say that for proper module deployment I need rearrange parent nodes and specify specific order position under parent node.
In following snapshot I put previously existed `personalizationActivation` folder under new `personalizationActivation` parent and set my handler before `personalizationActivation`

[image]

What I should export:

1. parent `personalizationActivation`
2. or just my `contextLoggerCommand` node and than adjust it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your new `personalizationActivation` node. Alternatively you could also repeat whole sequence of operations you described with update tasks, but it's easier to do in single step (export).

While doing so, also make sure your module (the one that will be bootstrapping this new configuration) has declared dependency (in module descriptor) on personalization module, to make sure it will bootstrap it's changes *after* personalization and doesn't get overriden by it.

In the future, you might want to scan release notes and update warnings regularly for updates in personalization to make sure that if there's ever change in this command, you will notice it and replicate in your new configuration.

HTH,
Jan